# SQL - Trying to count records based on CASE WHEN (SIMPLE?)

Tags: sql, count, case

Extremely simple case - I can't calculate properly the number of months for below table - the expected number is 2, not 3 - what is interesting the "valueagg" is calculated properly with same condition!

```
INSERT INTO ForgeRock
    ([productName], [description], [month], [value] )
VALUES
    ('OpenIDM', 'Y',1,33.2),
    ('OpenIDM', 'Y',2, 12.1),
    ('OpenIDM', 'Y',3, 1.1)
;
```

TEST

```
SELECT
  productName,
  description,
    sum(CASE WHEN [MONTH] between 1 and 2 then [VALUE] else 0 end) valueagg    --works
 ,count(CASE WHEN [MONTH] between 1 and 2 then [MONTH] else 0 end) month_count --doesn't work
 ,count(CASE WHEN [MONTH] between 1 and 2 then 1 else 0 end) month_count2      --doesn't work
FROM
  ForgeRock
  group by   productName,
  description
```

RESULT

```
| productName | description |           valueagg | month_count | month_count2 |
|-------------|-------------|--------------------|-------------|--------------|
|     OpenIDM |           Y | 45.300000000000004 |           3 |            3 |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/14603/3/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `count()` with `else`.  `count()` counts the number of non-`NULL` values and -- `0` is just as "not NULL" as any other value.

Use `sum()` instead:

```
SELECT productName, description,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [MONTH] between 1 and 2 then [VALUE] else 0 end) as valueagg    --works
       SUM(CASE WHEN [MONTH] between 1 and 2 then [MONTH] else 0 end) as month_count --doesn't work
       SUM(CASE WHEN [MONTH] between 1 and 2 then 1 else 0 end) month_count2      --doesn't work
FROM ForgeRock
GROUP BY productName, description
```

Or remove the `ELSE` from the `COUNT()`.

Comment: Thanks, just used sum in last column 15 sec ago :) Thanks for COUNT() logic explanation, I wasn't aware (or didn't remember) of that...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ELSE part of the CASE expressions:

```
SELECT
  productName,
  description,
    sum(CASE WHEN [MONTH] between 1 and 2 then [VALUE] else 0 end) valueagg
    ,count(CASE WHEN [MONTH] between 1 and 2 then [MONTH] end) month_count
FROM
  ForgeRock
  group by   productName,
  description
```

or replace with `SUM()` like this:

```
SELECT
  productName,
  description,
    sum(CASE WHEN [MONTH] between 1 and 2 then [VALUE] else 0 end) valueagg
    ,sum(CASE WHEN [MONTH] between 1 and 2 then 1 else 0 end) month_count
FROM
  ForgeRock
  group by   productName,
  description
```